# Excel VBA - Merge columns in X rows based on number of filtered rows in adjacent worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I have a worksheet (wsA) that I need to merge columns B and C for a variable amount of rows based on a filtered range in worksheet (wsB) (both in the same workbook).

For example, in wsB, if the data has been filtered so that only 4 rows (not including the header) show, then in wsA I need, starting at row 12, B12 and C12 to merge, B13 and C13, B14 and C14, and finally B15 and C15.

The numbers of rows merged in wsA will always be based on the number of rows that exist in the filtered data from wsB.  It could be 0, and it could be 100 or more.

I attempted the below code, but it just appears to mirror the existing rows in wsB by merging those rows in wsA:

```
filledRows = wsB.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
wsA.Range("B12:C" & filledRows).Merge
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you please provide before and after pictures? Not 100% clear what you want. That said, if you want `B12:C12` to merge, then `B13:C13` to merge, you need to loop through each row and merge the two cells together, being mindful that whatever is in column c will be deleted in the merge... but again, I'm not 100% certain what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue, the code should be as follows:

```
filteredLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
filledRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & filteredLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
Range("B12:C" & filledRows + 12).Merge True
```